# how to run the .js code in linux

Tags: nodejs

When I run the .js code, I get the error like this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

And I try to upgrade the nodejs using:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -`

then it tells me "curl: command not found"

I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

To install `curl`, run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install curl
```

Or you could use `wget` instead, but I'm not sure what the equivalent options would be.